# GSON to Json with Complex HashMap structure

Tags: java, gson

Trying out gson for a minecraft plugin I am writing, im getting some nasty errors and im a little stuck. I think I know whats throwing it off. I hafe a structure I will post in order. Here is my structure:

```
public class PlayerCharacter {
    protected Player owner;
    protected PlayerCollections playerCollections;
}
```

```
public class PlayerCollections {
    protected Player owner;
    private HashMap<Material, Collection> unlockedCollections = new HashMap<>(); //issue?
}
```

```
public class Collection extends PlayerCollections {
    private Material collection;
    private int level;
    private int collected;
    private String collectionDisplayName;
    private int nextLevelAmountRequired;

    private ArrayList<String> configLevels = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Im getting a null error and type adapter errors. Now, I think its because of the hashmap im using. This hashmap is technically null, was hoping it would just be ignored until something is stored there but I also think it just doesnt know what to do with my "collections" class and "material"

Im trying to do a toJson on the "PlayerCharacter" class

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
PlayerCharacter playerCharacter = KRYMMO.getPlayerStats(event.getPlayer());

utils.savePlayerGson(playerCharacter);
```

```
    public static PlayerCharacter getPlayerStats(Player player) {
        PlayerCharacter playerCharacter;

        if (playerStatsMap.containsKey(player)) {
            return playerStatsMap.get(player);
        } else {
            playerCharacter = new PlayerCharacter(player);
            playerStatsMap.put(player, playerCharacter);

            return playerCharacter;
        }
    }
```

```
    public static void savePlayerGson(PlayerCharacter playerCharacter) {
        String json = new Gson().toJson(playerCharacter);
    }
```

Error:
https://pastebin.com/V24XrbTx

Comment: Without seeing any code which actually produces the error/problem or even the JSON, we can only guess. So make sure you include a [mre] so we can test the problem. However you've said the hash map is null, which is not the case here, are you confusing null with empty?

Comment: Add stack traces too.

Comment: probably am confusing null with empty. Let me grab the stack traces. As for the repoducing code, im just initializing the classes and letting the defaults be the defaults.

Comment: I have updated my post, apologies. I can post full classes if needed, the rest of the class are int/strings for the class and getter/setters inside the class

Comment: It would be nice if you'd provide the full source code of the data classes, because the following are missing: `Player` and `Material`.
(By the way, do they have `equals` and `hashCode` properly implemented?)
A minimal working example is required to diagnose the real issue, otherwise it can't be diagnosed.

Comment: Then:
* I would also not recommend your `Collection` to have such a name due to a name clash with `java.util.Collection` whose name is very often used.
* And I would also recommend not to use concrete types for fields, but prefer their closest interfaces (`List<String>` and `Map<Material, Collection>`).
* `Gson` instances can be made `static` without any negative impact (+ it would just work faster).
* JSON cannot have complex objects as object keys (like your maps are), but Gson has a special workaround: `enableComplexMapKeySerialization` makes Gson save such maps as _[n][2]_-arrays.

Comment: Gotcha I can try that. Material and Player are part of the minecraft source code. I do not have that source. Material does have a to string method though. Might just have to change my player variable to something like the UUID

Comment: @SamuelHeinicke Yes, it will be the most natural choice since UUIDs can always server as map keys. It makes the code and JSON a bit more complex but it also makes it much more flexible and retain no redundant data. Additionally, `java.util.UUID` has `equals` and `hashCode` properly implemented so your maps will work.

Comment: Thank you! Changing my value from player to UUID actually fixed my error!